# Плавное появление контента в новом окне. Запрет на панель управления видео

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, видео, img

Всем доброго времени суток.
Есть код. Контент (изображения или видео) открывается в новом окне.
Как реализовать плавную смену (открытие) контента в этом окне? 
Плюс вопрос - при открытии видео в этом новом окне все равно остается панель управления видео. Как убрать?

```js
var window_objects = [];

function windowOpen(event) {


  event.preventDefault();
  var ref_href = event.currentTarget.href;
  var ref_target = event.currentTarget.target;


  window_objects[ref_target] = window.open(
    ref_href,
    ref_target,
    'top=0, left=0, height=400,width=400,menubar=no,directories=no,status=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,controls=no'
  );
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="10" align="center">
  <caption align="top">Proj</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Video</th>
    <th>Image</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="file:///c:/dir/vid/v1.mp4" target="project" onclick="windowOpen(event)"><video src="file:///c:/dir/vid/v1.mp4" width="360" height="240"></video>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="file:///c:/dir/img/i1.jpg" target="project" onclick="windowOpen(event)"><img src="file:///c:/dir/img/i1.jpg" width="360" height="240" />
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="file:///c:/dir/vid/v2.mp4" target="project" onclick="windowOpen(event)"><video src="file:///c:/dir/vid/v2.mp4" width="360" height="240"></video>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="file:///c:/dir/img/i2.jpg" target="project" onclick="windowOpen(event)"><img src="file:///c:/dir/img/i2.jpg" width="360" height="240" />
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: У вас ошибка в теге `video`. <video src="file:///c:/dir/vid/v2.mp4" width="360" height="240"></video> слеш в конце открывающего  тега лишний. И у  `<img>` тоже

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение. Но на работоспособность кода не влияло.

Comment: У меня критовало..